# Why does my computer continue to start Windows automatically after installing Ubuntu?

Tags: 12.04, installation, dual-boot

I tried to install Ubuntu: I loaded it on CD drive and clicked onto "Install Ubuntu" (not "Try Ubuntu"). Then in the window ("Preparing to install Ubuntu") I clicked onto "Continue", then in the next window I chose "wireless" and clicked "Continue".

As installation type I chose "Install Ubuntu alongside Windows 7". After that it showed "Restart to Continue".

When I clicked on "Restart and Continue" a black screen like a command prompt appeared and displayed something like:

- checking battery state
- checking for running unattended-upgrades: speech-dispatcher disable; edit /etc/default/speech-dispatcher
- asking all remaining processes to terminate

Finally after a few seconds the message "Please remove installation media and close the tray (if any) then press enter" appears.

My PC is an ASUS K43SJ core i5.

I didn't follow any guidance because my experience isn't enough in Linux.

Comment: And did you reboot then again? What happened? I again recommend to follow this guide: http://www.ubuntu.com/download/help/install-ubuntu-with-windows.

Comment: That sounds like it went well, then. Reboot. You should now have Ubuntu installed.

Comment: did You remove the CD?

Comment: What happened when you removed the CD and pressed Enter?

Comment: there was no different between remove cd or close cd drive with cd,windows loading automatically

Comment: windows loading

Comment: Try to press "Shift" directly after bios screen and see if GRUB appears.

Answer (score 0):

Try to get in Windows booting options (in msconfig) and set the time that other systems are displayed while booting to lets say 20 seconds. Does that help?

Comment: I solved grub problem by boot-repair (maybe solved) and by this command ......sudo mount /dev/sda6 /mnt
sudo grub-install --root-directory=/mnt /dev/sda ...... but install ubuntu inside windows option don't appear